# Trying to receive object in route - Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, routes

I've been struggling with a problem the last couple of days. I build my application with a backend of **Laravel** and the frontend of **Vue**. Now I want to get data from the backend through **Vue**, this is done by an **Axios** call. When I call the route I just want to call an object (which is set, already tested), but when it is returned it I empty? We tried `json_encode`, `response()->json()`, but without luck.

Our route:

```
Route::get('/pageSpeed', function(Request $request){
    $ps = new PageSpeedAPIController($request->url);
    $ps = $ps->getData();
    return response()->json($ps);
});
```

This is calling `getData` in our controller. Below you see the `getData` function.

```
public function getData() {
    return $this->getPageStats();
}
```

Hope you guys understand the problem and maybe have a solution for it :)

Comment: Where is the Axios call?

Comment: The Axios call isnt the issue. If we return the getters on the object we actually get the data. So the Axios call is working. So thought i wasnt nessecary :)